# What is the difference between Undoing and Reaction Formation?

Tags: psychoanalysis

According to wikipedia:

> **Reaction formation** is a defense mechanism in which emotions and impulses which are anxiety-producing or perceived to be unacceptable are mastered by exaggeration of the directly opposing tendency

> **Undoing** is a defense mechanism in which a person tries to cancel out or remove an unhealthy, destructive or otherwise threatening thought or action by engaging in contrary behavior

Both defense mechanisms seem to be reacting to an unhealthy thought with the opposite. Is there a quality that differentiates the two mechanisms?

Wikipedia links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_formation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undoing_(psychology)

Comment: This is a good explanation differentiating the two: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/hide-and-seek/201902/self-deception-part-6-reaction-formation